# Which anova model is the correct one (R)?

Tags: r, anova, experiment-design, inference

I have measured running times with 4 different systems (1 gold standard) and 4 different running styles.
Every run was carried out by 6 athletes, who were measured by all systems simultaneously. 
Now I want to analyse my data using an anova, but I'm not quite sure what the correct model is.

Overall my dataset looks like this:

```
Style    |  System 1 | System 2 | System 3
..........................................
A (N=12) |     e      |     e     |    e
B (N=6)  |     e      |     e     |    e
C (N=30) |     e      |     e     |    e
D (N=24) |     e      |     e     |    e
```

What I'm interested in is the error between the gold standard and the other systems, so each datapoint *e = t(gold standard) - t(system)*.

So if I'm not mistaken the structre of my setup is the following (the different athletes are are not considered as a factor):

```
Variable of interest: e
Factor 1: System (3 levels)
Factor 2: Style (5 levels)

Model in R:
aov(e ~ System*Style)
```

Now here is the point where I begin to stand in the rain. The more I read, the more confused I get. 
If I understood everything correct I have an unbalanced design which requires R to use Type III sums of squares specificly. But therefore I need to use a different function like e.g. Anova() from 'car' package.
What is the best way I should do my analysis?

On a side note, what about mixed effects anova, is this something I have to consider here? I can only find clinical examples and don't know if it's compareable to my design? If played around with the ezANOVA function from the 'ez' package, but im not sure about the correct model (wid, within, between parameters).

Thanks in advance and please let me know if I was unclear or need to give more information.

**Edit:**
added an example of my dataframe, maybe this clarifies the situation a bit more.

```
str(df)
'data.frame':   272 obs. of  4 variables:
$ Style   : Factor w/ 4 levels "1","2","3","4": 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 ...
$ Id    : int  6 8 13 14 18 30 6 8 13 14 ...
$ System: Factor w/ 4 levels "A","B",..: 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
$ e     : num  0.54 0.57 0.59 0.54 0.51 0.72 0.43 0.44 0.48 0.39 ...

head(df)
Run Id System    e
1    6     A  0.54
1    8     A  0.57
1   13     A  0.59 
1   14     A  0.54
1   18     A  0.51
1   30     A  0.72
...
2    6     A  0.48
...
1    6     B  0.96
...
```

Comment: Does your design involve repeated measures? If so you absolutely need to be considering a mixed effects model.

Comment: It took me too long to edit my first comment, sorry!  I added a bit more detail in the original question.  My measurements were done by 6 athletes, but each run was only carried out once per person.  I'm not quite sure if it counts as repeated measures, because all data values were collected in parallel per person. On the other hand there was a replication for each style because of the persons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have simulated some data that is similar to yours. Note that although I am running this analysis as a mixed effects model using the `lmer` function in the `lme4` package that I did not simulate the data in a way that highlights the existence of random intercepts at the level of the individual.

```
library(lme4)
library(lmerTest)

#simulate data... 
set.seed(123321)

#Group A
ID<-rep(1:12, times=3)
Style<-rep("A", length(ID))
Sys<-rep(1:3, each=12)
e<-rnorm(36, .60, .80)

groupA<-data.frame(ID, Style, Sys, e)

#Group B 
ID<-rep(13:18, times=3)
Style<-rep("B", length(ID))
Sys<-rep(1:3, each=6)
e<-rnorm(18, .40, 1.2)

groupB<-data.frame(ID, Style, Sys, e)

#Group C
ID<-rep(19:48, times=3)
Style<-rep("C", length(ID))
Sys<-rep(1:3, each=30)
e<-rnorm(90, .35, .90)

groupC<-data.frame(ID, Style, Sys, e)

#Group D
ID<-rep(49:72, times=3)
Style<-rep("D", length(ID))
Sys<-rep(1:3, each=24)
e<-rnorm(72, .60, 1.3)

groupD<-data.frame(ID, Style, Sys, e)

DF<-rbind(groupA, groupB, groupC, groupD)

#Lmer Model (one option)
fit<-lmer(e~1+as.factor(Sys)*Style+(1|ID), data=DF)
summary(fit)
```

The results are displayed below. Using the `lmerTest` wrap around package provides a means of extracting significance tests from mixed effects models.

```
> summary(fit)
Linear mixed model fit by REML t-tests use Satterthwaite approximations to degrees of freedom [lmerMod]
Formula: e ~ 1 + as.factor(Sys) * Style + (1 | ID)
   Data: DF

REML criterion at convergence: 633.1

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.6066 -0.6663  0.0193  0.5013  3.2567 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 ID       (Intercept) 0.05721  0.2392  
 Residual             1.05726  1.0282  
Number of obs: 216, groups:  ID, 72

Fixed effects:
                        Estimate Std. Error        df t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)              0.59932    0.30475 202.93000   1.967   0.0506 .
as.factor(Sys)2          0.37873    0.41977 136.00000   0.902   0.3685  
as.factor(Sys)3          0.06598    0.41977 136.00000   0.157   0.8753  
StyleB                  -0.09523    0.52784 202.93000  -0.180   0.8570  
StyleC                  -0.08040    0.36059 202.93000  -0.223   0.8238  
StyleD                  -0.16373    0.37324 202.93000  -0.439   0.6614  
as.factor(Sys)2:StyleB   0.32624    0.72707 136.00000   0.449   0.6544  
as.factor(Sys)3:StyleB   0.23596    0.72707 136.00000   0.325   0.7460  
as.factor(Sys)2:StyleC  -0.61468    0.49668 136.00000  -1.238   0.2180  
as.factor(Sys)3:StyleC  -0.19955    0.49668 136.00000  -0.402   0.6885  
as.factor(Sys)2:StyleD  -0.07710    0.51412 136.00000  -0.150   0.8810  
as.factor(Sys)3:StyleD   0.12904    0.51412 136.00000   0.251   0.8022  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) as.(S)2 as.(S)3 StyleB StyleC StyleD a.(S)2:SB a.(S)3:SB a.(S)2:SC a.(S)3:SC
as.fctr(S)2 -0.689                                                                             
as.fctr(S)3 -0.689  0.500                                                                      
StyleB      -0.577  0.398   0.398                                                              
StyleC      -0.845  0.582   0.582   0.488                                                      
StyleD      -0.816  0.562   0.562   0.471  0.690                                               
as.f(S)2:SB  0.398 -0.577  -0.289  -0.689 -0.336 -0.325                                        
as.f(S)3:SB  0.398 -0.289  -0.577  -0.689 -0.336 -0.325  0.500                                 
as.f(S)2:SC  0.582 -0.845  -0.423  -0.336 -0.689 -0.475  0.488     0.244                       
as.f(S)3:SC  0.582 -0.423  -0.845  -0.336 -0.689 -0.475  0.244     0.488     0.500             
as.f(S)2:SD  0.562 -0.816  -0.408  -0.325 -0.475 -0.689  0.471     0.236     0.690     0.345   
as.f(S)3:SD  0.562 -0.408  -0.816  -0.325 -0.475 -0.689  0.236     0.471     0.345     0.690   
            a.(S)2:SD
as.fctr(S)2          
as.fctr(S)3          
StyleB               
StyleC               
StyleD               
as.f(S)2:SB          
as.f(S)3:SB          
as.f(S)2:SC          
as.f(S)3:SC          
as.f(S)2:SD          
as.f(S)3:SD  0.500
```

This model allows you to include all of your observations and consider the fact that each individual case has its own random intercept that deviates from the grand mean of your dependent variable. The interactions can be specified in multiple ways to make your multiple comparisons. The default in R is to identify reference groups in order alphabetically or numerically. Therefore in this case, the reference groups for each variable were 1 for System and A for Style. This latter point is relevant when it comes time to interpret your interaction effects.

Comment: wow, this is awesome! Thank you so much for your effort, thats better than any christmas gift I can think of.  I will go thoroughly through it to learn as much as possible from your answer!

Comment: Happy to help. Good luck with the analyses.